# Can I implement Google Guava Search in SearchView

Tags: android, guava, searchview

I'm using SearchView in my with Custom List. It shows wrong result i.e. same result every time(First item of the list). 
So, I try to use Google's Gauva Filter and it works great when I log the result after filter. But now I don't know how to integrate it with my listview.

**here is my code of CustomList.java**
package com.jarvis.easysplay.adapter;

```
    public class CustomList extends ArrayAdapter  implements Filterable{
    private String[] names;
    private String[] desc;
    private Integer[] imageid;
    private Activity context;

    public CustomList(Activity context, String[] names, String[] desc) {
        super(context, R.layout.list_item, names);
        this.context = context;
        this.names = names;
        this.desc = desc;
//        this.imageid = imageid;

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        View listViewItem = inflater.inflate(R.layout.song_list_layout, null, true);
        TextView textViewName = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.song_title);
        TextView textViewDesc = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.song_author);
        ImageView image = (ImageView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
//        TextView options = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.options);

        //Set Data
        textViewName.setText(names[position]);
        textViewDesc.setText(desc[position]);
        return  listViewItem;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return super.getFilter();
    }

}
```

**And this is my Search Filter Code:-**

```
   public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.music_search, menu);
        MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.music_search_bar);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();
        searchView.setQueryHint("Search Song");
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
//                SongFragment.this.customList.getFilter().filter(newText); //I used this but it is not working
                List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
                list.addAll(arrayList);
                List<String> filteredList = Lists.newArrayList(Collections2.filter(
                        list, Predicates.contains(Pattern.compile(newText,Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE))));
                String[] stringArray = filteredList.toArray(new String[0]);
                CustomList custom = new CustomList(getActivity(),stringArray,stringArray);
                custom.getFilter().filter(newText);

                Log.d("searchResult",filteredList.toString());
                return false;

            }
        });

        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }
```

Can anybody tell me how can I use Google's Guava in my code or how to get Correct Result by using without using google's Guava filter.
I did so much google and also try many solutions but it didn't work :(.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're creating a new `CustomList` adapter, but you aren't doing anything with it. You'll need to install the new adapter in your ListView or whatever AdapterView you are using. If you're using a ListView, you could call `ListView.setAdapter(custom)`. You probably don't need to mix and match filtering using `Filterable` and filtering by Guava.

Comment: Now, I'm getting position 1 of resulted item. I want the real position of that item as in previous list view. Is there any way to do that?